# perl List::AllUtils uniq & sort

Tags: perl

Trying this:

```
perl -Mv5.14 -MList::AllUtils=uniq -E 'my(@x) = qw(2 3 1 2); say "@x"; my(@y) = uniq @x; say "@y"'
```

It correctly prints

```
2 3 1 2
2 3 1
```

Now want the sorted output, so tried:

```
perl -Mv5.14 -MList::AllUtils=uniq -E 'my(@x) = qw(2 3 1 2); say "@x"; my(@y) = sort uniq @x; say "@y"'
```

Surprisingly it prints:

```
2 3 1 2
2 1 3 2
```

Switching the order of the `uniq` and `sort`

```
perl -Mv5.14 -MList::AllUtils=uniq -E 'my(@x) = qw(2 3 1 2); say "@x"; my(@y) = uniq sort @x; say "@y"'
```

gives the correct result

```
2 3 1 2
1 2 3
```

So, compared them using the `MO=Deparse`.

The 1st:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -Mv5.14 -MList::AllUtils=uniq -E 'my(@x) = qw(2 3 1 2); say "@x"; my(@y) = uniq @x; say "@y"'
sub BEGIN {
    require v5.14;
}
use List::AllUtils (split(/,/u, 'uniq', 0));
use strict;
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'postderef_qq', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
my(@x) = ('2', '3', '1', '2');
say join($", @x);
my(@y) = &uniq(@x);
say join($", @y);
-e syntax OK
```

the second:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -Mv5.14 -MList::AllUtils=uniq -E 'my(@x) = qw(2 3 1 2); say "@x"; my(@y) = sort uniq @x; say "@y"'
sub BEGIN {
    require v5.14;
}
use List::AllUtils (split(/,/u, 'uniq', 0));
use strict;
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'postderef_qq', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
my(@x) = ('2', '3', '1', '2');
say join($", @x);
my(@y) = (sort uniq @x);
say join($", @y);
-e syntax OK
```

third:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -Mv5.14 -MList::AllUtils=uniq -E 'my(@x) = qw(2 3 1 2); say "@x"; my(@y) = uniq sort @x; say "@y"'
sub BEGIN {
    require v5.14;
}
use List::AllUtils (split(/,/u, 'uniq', 0));
use strict;
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'postderef_qq', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
my(@x) = ('2', '3', '1', '2');
say join($", @x);
my(@y) = &uniq(sort(@x));
say join($", @y);
-e syntax OK
```

The difference is how the `uniq` subroutine is called:

```
my(@y) = (sort uniq @x);  # sort uniq @x
my(@y) = &uniq(sort(@x)); # uniq sort @x
```

I understand than the `uniq` is an subroutine provided by the `List::AllUtils` and the `sort` is an builtin function, but using the `uniq` as:

```
my(@y) = &uniq(sort(@x));
```

doesn't seems for me very intutive.

Must I use it in the `&uniq(...)` form, e.g. with `&` and parenthesis? Coudl someone please add some more info about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run it with `use strict` and `use warnings` it tells you what is wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::AllUtils 'uniq';

my (@x) = qw(2 3 1 2);
say "@x";
my (@y) = sort uniq @x;
say "@y";
```

This gives the warning *Sort subroutine didn't return single value at*. `sort` thinks that `uniq` is the subroutine that it should use to sort the list.

[The `sort` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) explains this.

> sort SUBNAME LIST
>   sort BLOCK LIST
>   sort LIST

You can also give it a sub name. It's a bit counter-intuitive to use that subname directy (i.e. not as a string, or as a code reference), but that's how it is supposed to be. There even is an example in the docs.

> ```
> # sort using explicit subroutine name
> sub byage {
>     $age{$a} <=> $age{$b};  # presuming numeric
> }
> my @sortedclass = sort byage @class;
> ```

So in this case, it treats your `uniq` not as _call `uniq(@x)` and sort the return value using the default `sort` behaviour, but instead it does *sort `@x` using `uniq` as the sorting function*.

---

You can make `sort` ignore the sub name and use the return value instead by prepending a `+` sign.

```
my (@x) = qw(2 3 1 2);
say "@x";
my (@y) = sort +uniq @x;
say "@y";

__END__
2 3 1 2
1 2 3
```

And there is no warning now. `sort +uniq(@x)` also works, and is easier to read.

Comment: Using the -Mv5.14 enables the `strict` and even your example with the `warnings` doesn't prints any warning. At least for me - using `v5.24.0`.

Comment: @kobame hmm that's strange. I've got 5.20. But that's still what is happening. Warning or no warning. You are overwriting the default behaviour by giving it a sub name

Comment: `sort(uniq(@x))` works fine, as long as there's no space after `uniq`